# Accessing Properties in Static Library in iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a objective-C static library ( iOS SDK 6 ):

**Implementation file ( .m )**

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
static id _instance;
static NSString *version;

- (id)init {
    if(_instance == nil) {
        _instance = [super init];
        version = @"1.0";
    }
    return _instance;
}

- (NSString *)getVersion {
    return version;
}

+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance {
    return _instance;
}

@end
```

When I access the class in other iPhone App project (imported the library), I cannot get the version string.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MyClass/MyClass.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyClass *cls = [MyClass sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Loaded. Version: %@", [cls getVersion]);
}
@end
```

What did I miss? No error is reported, but version is `(null)`

Comment: can you show the implementation of summon?.

Comment: sorry, it should be `sharedInstance` instead of `summon`

Comment: Is init really called?. I don't think so.

Comment: try printing id cls, and confirm its class type. I think thats where you missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lot of mistakes ...

- `init` is not called at all
- etc.

... you seem try to use singleton pattern. So, do this ...

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance {
  static MyClass *instance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    instance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
  });
  return instance;
}
```

... and change your `init` to ...

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if ( !self ) {
    return nil;
  }

  _version = @"1.0";
  return self;
}
```

... and call `[[MyClass sharedInstance] getVersion]` to get your version.

P.S. Read ObjC guide and don't use `get` prefix. Should be just `version`.

Comment: sorry for my newbie `Obj-C` skills. Seems I followed a wrong tutorial. Now working well. But I don't understand why `dispatch_once` is required.

Comment: `dispatch_once` calls the block just once, it means that your class `sharedInstance` method always returns the same object. Read this for example - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern